# How to get CSS Hover Transform to work with relative positioning

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BradMitchell/kaouzm73/)

I have heading text with an arrow next to it. When you hover over the text, the arrow translates. It works with `position: absolute` but I need it to work with `position: relative`.

How do I achieve this?

```css
#container {
  width: 130px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container h2:after {
  transition: all 1s ease
}

#container:hover h2:after {
  transform: translateX(30px);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#container h2:after {
  content: "->";
  position: absolute;
  /* It currently works with absolute positioning, but I want it to work with relative positioning. */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Go to my website</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `#container h2::after` to `display: inline-block`

```
#container h2::after {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

*Sidenote:* even though `h2:after` is not wrong, elements created with `before` and `after` are written with 2 colons, while pseudo-classes (like `:hover`) only use 1 colon.

Answer (score 0):

Combined two of your h2:after styles for cleaner code, changed transform to margin-left for css to allow for transitioning effects and changed position to relative on the h2. Let me know if you have any questions.

```css
#container {
  width: 130px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container h2:after {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  content: "->";
  position: relative;
}

#container:hover h2:after {
  margin-left: 30px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Go to my website</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:inline-block` to pseudo element

```css
#container {
  width: 130px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container h2:after {
  transition: all 1s ease
}

#container h2:after {
  content: "->";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* It currently works with absolute positioning, but I want it to work with relative positioning. */
}

#container:hover h2:after {
  transform: translateX(30px);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Go to my website</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use margin-left instead transform

https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/L8ce3m4q/

```
#container h2:after {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  margin-left:5px;
}

#container:hover h2:after {
  margin-left:25px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#container h2:after {
  content: "->";
  position: relative;

}
```

Comment: `transform` renders smoother than `margin-left`